# Pass a value to a Javascript function from C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have this javascript function in a .aspx file.

```
<script>
    function somefun(value)
    {

    }
<script>
```

I'm calling and passing a value to that function inside the code-behind class.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Passing", String.Format("somefun('{0}');", filePath1), false);
```

But when it runs, the function doesn't work properly. I'm getting an printed output like this

"**somefun(the content of the variable)**"

What would be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Passing", String.Format("somefun('{0}');", filePath1), false);
```

Source:http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb350750(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

First, I like to use a function to Execute Javascript code on the client browser...

```
#region ExecuteJavascript
private int _intScriptIndex = 0;
private void ExecuteJavascript(string strScript)
{
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "ExecuteScript" + _intScriptIndex++, strScript, true);
}
#endregion
```

Now I just call  JavaScript like this...

```
ExecuteJavascript("alert('test');");
```

To call a function with variables you would do this...

```
ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("somefun('{0}');", filePath1));
```

That should do it. The key to why mine works and yours doesn't is probably in the properties of RegisterStartupScript, notice that I pass Page and typeof(Page) where you put string.

Comment: Yeah, ExecuteJavascript("alert('test');"); works.    But the ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("somefun('{0}');", filePath1)); gives an error.    Error: Unable to get property 'SetVariable' of undefined or null reference

Comment: somefun('Test.txt');

This is syntactically correct, the SetVariable error you are getting must be a Javascript error unrelated to the code executing in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Passing", "somefun('" + filePath1 + "');" ,false);
```

Comment: string concatenation with + is functionally equivalent to string.format. Your suggestion will make no difference

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

C# code:

```
String vls_variable = "TestData";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "script1", "SampleJSFunction('" + vls_variable + "');", true);
```

JavaScript function:

```
function SampleJSFunction(variable) 
{  
    var data = variable;
    alert("working");            
}
```